# How to hard code simple authentication (no backend) and redirect to home page - React

Tags: reactjs

I am building simple react app with couple of routes for a test job interview. Some of the routes I already implemented are Todos, Users and Login, that is basically all the routes I need. For now I as a user have access to all routes which is not what I won't. I would like to when app runs it get redirected to Login route/page and after successful authentication app goes/redirect to home page. The task I got for my interview is to hard-code user credentials and use those.

I implemented Todo, Users and Login routes and navbar menu so I am able to navigate across my app, now the only problem is how to do this basic hard-coded auth.

On the Internet, videos and tutorials I have find only hard and complicated auth implementations with helper functions, services and fake and/or real backend services for authentication which is what I don't need for this simple task. Can anyone show me how this can be done if it can. Thanks in advance...

this is my App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Todo from "./components/Todo";
import Users from "./components/Users";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <NavBar />
          <Route path="/" exact component={Users}></Route>
          <Route path="/login" exact component={Login}></Route>
          <Route path="/todo" component={Todo}></Route>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this is my Login Component:

```
import React from "react";

function Login() {
  return (
    <div className="login-page">
      <h2>Login In</h2>
      <form autoComplete="off">
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="email"
            className="form-control"
            id="exampleInputEmail1"
            aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            placeholder="Enter email"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="password"
            autoComplete="new-password"
            className="form-control"
            id="exampleInputPassword1"
            placeholder="Password"
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming security does not matter and you just need a quick solution, you could set a token in sessionStorage, and check if user has that token upon load.

Your login page:

```
const [emailInput, setEmailInput] = useState('');
const [passwordInput, setPasswordInput] = useState('');

const history = useHistory();

const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmailInput(e.target.value);
}

const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPasswordInput(e.target.value);
}

const handleLoginSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let hardcodedCred = {
        email: 'email@email.com',
        password: 'password123'
    }

    if ((emailInput == hardcodedCred.email) && (passwordInput == hardcodedCred.password)) {
        //combination is good. Log them in.
        //this token can be anything. You can use random.org to generate a random string;
        const token = '123456abcdef';
        sessionStorage.setItem('auth-token', token);
        //go to www.website.com/todo
        history.push('/todo');
    } else {
        //bad combination
        alert('wrong email or password combination');
    }
}

return (
    <div className="login-page">
        <h2>Login In</h2>
        <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleLoginSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control"
                id="exampleInputEmail1"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                placeholder="Enter email"
                value={emailInput}
                onChange={handleEmailChange}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input
                type="password"
                autoComplete="new-password"
                className="form-control"
                id="exampleInputPassword1"
                placeholder="Password"
                value={passwordInput}
                onChange={handlePasswordChange}
                />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                Submit
            </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

And then wherever you want to check if the user is authorized:

```
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('auth-token')) {
    console.log('no auth token set');
    //do something like redirect to login page
} else {
    const authToken = '123456abcdef';
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('auth-token') == authToken) {
        console.log('good token. Log in.')
        //do something like redirect to todo page
    } else {
        console.log('bad token.')
        //do something like redirect to login page
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about email and password, just "hard-code user credentials" which could mean anything. To clarify - you're looking for help to create a function that will check user email & password input, and if it's good then redirect to another page?

Comment: Sorry I didn't my bed, and again there is my Login component in which there is login form with email and password inputs which indicates that that should be user credentials

Comment: @Pokreniseweb I updated the code, check it out and let me know what you think

Comment: this look promising I am going to give it a try right now, but I am not sure where that conditional logic for checking if user is authenticated goes, maybe in App.js or?

Comment: Wherever you need to check if the user is authenticated. Based on your code it looks like it would make sense to put that in Todo.js. If you had a more robust app you could put it in places like BankAccount.js or Profile.js or anything

Comment: But what about redirection to login page. By default app will after initialisation go to home page on route '/' which is not '/login'

Comment: @Pokreniseweb You can import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom' and do history.push('/route'). I updated the code, check it out. Change todo to whatever you want

Comment: I did everything as you did and get useState is not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201682/discussion-between-pokreniseweb-and-radihuq).